# PHP & RSS Query from DB

Tags: php, database, rss

I have this query;

```
<?php
include '../thisfile.php';
include '../scripts/thisscript.php';
$this = $_GET ['this'] ;
$query = "SELECT this FROM tablename WHERE this='$this' LIMIT 1";
$feedlist = new rss ('.$row['this'].');
echo $feedlist->display(9,"this title");
?>
```

All works fine without the $query to the DB, what is wrong with my syntax here?

Essentially I want to pull feeds that are stored in my DB as I am using a PHP template to drive the pages.

Comment: `new rss ('.$row['this'].');` doesn't look right. I'm not sure what you're trying to pass to `rss()` but you either need to double-quote the argument (i.e. `new rss(".$row['this'].")`) or concatenate `this` into the string you're sending.

Comment: This code is utterly broken. You're not running a db query. You're just defining a string which happens to contain some sql. You're not fetching any data from your non-existence query, so `$row` is never defined, and you have syntax errors galore.

Comment: All the above, plus, you're going to want to learn to use descriptive variables names sooner rather than later, otherwise you will quickly find your code to be unmaintainable.

Comment: Thanks @RobHruska. You are the only one to offer a potential solution, alas I have tried the double quote to no avail :(